# If $f(x)$ is a polynomial and $f(n)$ is an integer for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $f(x)$ must have integer coefficients.

Tags: polynomials, examples-counterexamples, integers

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial and $f(n)$ is an integer for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $f(x)$ must have integer coefficients.

I need to disprove the statement via a counter-example. But I can't seem to think of one. Could $3x^2+2x^{-1}+1$ be a possible example?

Comment: How about $f(x)=x^2+\frac12x+1$ and $f(2)=6\in\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: Need more details.  Where must the coefficients of $f$ come from?  Real numbers?  And for all $n$, or only one $n$?

Comment: What about $f(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \pi x^2 + i \cdot x^3$? It has $f(0)=0$, and $0$ is an integer.

Comment: The example in the post is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another family of simpe counter-examples: By Fermat's little theorem, $x^p\equiv x\pmod p$ for all $x\in\Bbb Z$ if $p$ is prime. Therefore
$$\frac1px^p-\frac1px $$
maps integers to integers.

Answer (score 6):

Are you after a polynomial $p(x)$ such that not all of its coefficients are integer but such that nevertheless you have $p(n)\in\mathbb Z$ for each integer $n$? You can take $p(x)=\frac12x^2+\frac12x$, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

It is well known that the real polynomials with the given property are exactly the integer linear combinations of polynomials of the form $\binom{x}{n}$ (that is a binomial coefficient). 
José Carlos Santos' answer is a very good example which is almost exactly the simplest nontrivial one with non-integer coefficients, as $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{2}x = \binom{x}{2}+x$.

Try to prove the above by induction on the degree, or directly, it is not so hard. Then you have many counterexamples.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something more than a quadratic try $$\frac 16(x^3-x)$$

Comment: I am amazed by this but feel as though I shouldn't be.  What's the argument for seeing this?

Comment: Never mind, just got it.

Comment: @Randall There are various ways of seeing it - I thought of $\binom xn$ and wanted you to think about this, and also (essentially the same thing) that $n!$ divides the product of $n$ consecutive integers. I just made $x$ the middle of the three. I find it is sometimes computationally convenient to make the product of an odd number of consecutive integers symmetric if you can choose.